# Is it possible to call objective-c pushViewController from javascript

Tags: ios, ios5, cordova

Noob iOS dev - I would like to be able to call a detail controller from javascript in a UIWebView. Like a user clicks on a link and it calls pushViewController. Would I need phonegap to do this or is it possible just in javascript?

thx

Answer (score 0):

iOS only supports one-way JavaScript communication via UIWebView's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.

However, you can mimic two-way communication by setting up a periodic poller in your Obj C code that calls a javascript function which returns a variable value that is set by some JavaScript code on the web page.  You will have a noticable delay in the UI depending on the interval of your poller.

Comment: Probably not fully undertanding but we'd basically have to set up an NSTimer that would be checking whether a value is set in response to an event fired within the UIWebView? Like a user would click on a link that would be captured by jQuery which would set a global_value and then the controller that has the UIWebView would do a pushViewController on this?

Comment: Good.  The global value could be an integer that you increment in JavaScript every time the action is performed and which you also keep track of in the view controller so you can compare it on each firing of the timer.  If the value is different, then you know some action was taken.  You can have a seperate value for each distinct type of action that you want to monitor.